# How can I redirect on google site?

Tags: javascript, css, redirect, google-sites, forward

How can I redirect those who enter the site with a mobile phone to another page or send am message them on google site?

I used of this code but nothing special happens.

```js
if (window.innerWidth <= 500) {
  window.location.href = "https://example.com/";
}
```

I even used the alert command, but it didn't show anything. Is it possible to use JavaScript codes in Google site?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I assume that they are hosting their site with [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/).  It is a very basic site builder GUI that doesn't allow you to add arbitrary JavaScript to your pages.

Comment: @stephenOtermiller However I just checked with google sites and he actualy can add javascript code! [link](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en#:~:text=You%20can%20add%20files%20and,HTML%2C%20CSS%2C%20or%20JavaScript%20code) first paragraph. But his code is wrong even in another hosting won't work, that is why I suggested my code using event listener window.onload

Answer (score 1):

If you want those entering your website via mobile to be redirected to another URL (ex here `https://www.example.com/`) you can use the `window.onload` event listener, in that case if website is loaded on small screen (here `<700px`) they will be immediately redirected to google page. If you want on a resize event you can use the window.resize listener.

```
let windowWidth
window.onload = function() {       // redirection onload if screen width is <700px
  windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  if(windowWidth < 700){
    window.location.href='https://www.example.com/'
  }
};

window.onresize = function() {      // redirection if you resize and screen is <700px
  windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  if(windowWidth < 700){
    window.location.href='https://www.example.com/'
  }
};
```

Comment: @stephen Ostermiller you are correct Have not seen his additional lines below his code..

Comment: @stephenOtermiller However I just checked with google sites and he actualy can add javascript code! [link](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en) first paragraph. But his code is wrong even in another hosting won't work, that is why I suggested my code using event listener window.onload

Comment: Thanks a lot @StephenOtermiller. I do appreciate that . Enjoy coding as well!